# Doing something on backend depending on time

Tags: javascript, http, heroku, backend

I have single app deployed to Heroku. How can I make that my server will do request to some url for example every day in 7.00 pm? How can it work? I have heroku free plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out http://callmyapp.com/, it functions as a sort of web based chron. You can set it to send a request to your app at specific times.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need!

Answer (score 1):

"[Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) is an add-on for running jobs on your app at scheduled time intervals, much like cron in a traditional server environment."